# How to Form the Service Request if i have list<Class>

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Request Class Structure:

```
public class QueryParams {
    public List<QueryParam> QueryParam { get; set; }
}
public class QueryParam {
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Service is Expecting in below format:

```
<typ:queryParams>

    <typ:queryParam>
        <typ:parameter>BUSINESS_CATEGORY</typ:parameter>
    </typ:queryParam>

    <typ:queryParam>
        <typ:parameter>CATEGORY</typ:parameter>
    </typ:queryParam>

</typ:queryParams>
```

How i can form the request?

Answer (score 0):

```
using QueryParams = System.Collections.Generic.List<QueryParam>;

public class QueryParam {
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public QueryParam(string para) {
        Parameter = para;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var Qp = new QueryParams() {
            new QueryParam("BUSINESS_CATEGORY"),
            new QueryParam("CATEGORY")
        };
        string QpXml = ToXml(Qp);
        // Use your XML from here on
    }

    private static string ToXml(QueryParams Qp) {
        StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
        Sb.AppendLine("<typ:queryParams>");
        foreach (var q in Qp) {
            Sb.AppendLine("<typ:queryParam>");
            Sb.AppendLine("<typ:parameter>" + q.Parameter + "</typ:parameter>");
            Sb.AppendLine("</typ:queryParam>");
        }
        Sb.AppendLine("</typ:queryParams>");
        return Sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

See [this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ty5JlT)